# How to check pending android services, from the service function

Tags: android, service

If there were 2 services triggered at same time, the 1st service trigger will be executed 1st and the 2nd trigger will be queued up. 
Before killing the process of the 1st service trigger i want to check weather there were any pending service triggers or not.
if so, i want to start the service for the 2nd service trigger and kill this process.

Can this be done, Please let me know how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a BroadcastReceiver in your service that responds to pings from your activities. Register the BroadcastReceiver when the service starts, and unregister it when the service is destroyed. From your activity, send a local broadcast intent to the service and if it responds, you know it's running. This way you can achieve what you want to do.